# python - pxssh - failed to login

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I'm trying to connect to a server using ssh via the pxssh python library.
Here's my code:

```
import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.force_password = True
    hostname = 'myserverip'
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    s.login (hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline ('get system number')  # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print s.before         # print everything before the prompt.
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
    print "pxssh failed on login."
    print str(e)
```

Here is the response I am getting:

```
pxssh failed on login.
could not set shell prompt
 unset PROMPT_COMMAND

error,09
$ PS1='[PEXPECT]\$ '

error,09
$ set prompt='[PEXPECT]\$ '

error,09
$
```

Comment: (First Question Review) You might want to add the information which command is actually failing and what you did to solve the problem.

Comment: The command I did was `get system number` , and it says failed login.

Comment: I mean which line in the above python code. I suspect if you do not catch the exception it will print it. otherwise you can add debug output. But I guess it is the `s.prompt()`? Anyway it looks quite strange to do a terminal emulation to run commands with ssh.

Comment: That's all it output.

Comment: It looks like the shell on the remote system is not bash. Try setting `s.PROMPT` and passing `auto_prompt_reset=False` to login. Docs: http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pxssh.html#pexpect.pxssh.pxssh.PROMPT

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question but just for posterity. (For the one's who would bump in to this like me :) )

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
    username = raw_input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline('uptime')   # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print(s.before)        # print everything before the prompt.
    s.sendline('ls -l')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.sendline('df')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
    print(e)
```

which I just yanked from http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pxssh.html#pexpect.pxssh.pxssh

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the login credentials?
The logs indicate that your script didnt clear the first step necessary to get the shell.
s.login(hostname, username, password)
BTW, you are hardcoding all these arguments.
Your first problem here is that there is no hostname as 'hostname' which you can logon to on any system, unless alias of 'localhost' or some website/url.

Note: Use your head before blatantly copying examples.